# Does there exist a deterministic, invertible function $\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ that is not a bijection?

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation, bijection

One of the requirements for a function to be a PRP is

> - For any $K \in \{0,1\}^s$, $F$ is a bijection from $\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$.

[Taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation#Pseudorandom_permutation)

Does this have to be explicitly said? Is it even possible for this not to be true for a deterministic, invertible function where the input and output domains are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for fixed $n$, there does not exist an invertible function $\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ that is not a bijection.

For a function onto a finite set, bijection is synonymous with invertible. Notice that function implies definition over the full source set.

I see no mention of "invertible" in the quoted definition, thus "bijection" is not redundant. I do see some redundancy in the question: strictly speaking, every function is deterministic; however, *function* is sometime misused for something with a hidden random input, and *deterministic* function emphasizes that the input uniquely determines the output.

Comment: Indeed invertible is not mentioned in the wikipedia article and the "bijection" part of the definition is what makes this a PRP instead of a PRF.

Comment: Isn't every injective total function from a set to itself also a surjection?

Comment: I think your first statement is only true if the function is total: you can have a partial function that is injective on its image, and thus invertible, but not defined on every point of its domain.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this have to be explicitly said?

You stripped the preceding context from that quote:

> Let $F$ be a mapping $\{0,1\}^n × \{0,1\}^s → \{0,1\}^n$. $F$ is a PRP if
>
> - For any $K ∈ \{0,1\}^s$, $F$ is a bijection from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^n$.
> - [...]

Not all mappings $F : \{0,1\}^n × \{0,1\}^s → \{0,1\}^n$ are bijections for all choices of $K$, so yes, the definition certainly has to state the bijectivity requirement.

> Is it even possible for this not to be true for a deterministic, invertible function where the input and output domains are the same?

You're reading the definition with an implicit assumption in mind that the function must be invertible, but the clause you're pondering is the one that actually states the requirement.

Comment: "Not all mappings $F : \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^s \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ are bijections for all choices of $K$" Are you saying that there are choices of $K$ for which $F$ is **not** a bijection? Does this mean there are choices for $K$ such that $F_k(x) = F_k(y)$ where $y \neq x$?

Answer (score 2):

An invertible function must be injective, for if there were $x \ne y$ with $f(x) = f(y) = s$, it would not be possible to have an inverse function $g$: $g(s)$ can't equal both $x$ and $y$.

Further, a simple counting argument shows that an injection between two sets of equal cardinality must be a bijection. If the two sets are in fact the same, it is also called a *permutation*.